# Redirecting from javascript inside iframe canvas application but URL in browser doesnot change

Tags: facebook, browser

I am able to redirect inside my canvas application and show different pages with the following links:

```
window.location.href = "/Create/StartTime?mid=" + mid;
```

My issue is that inside the browser URL bar we cannot see any change in the address. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to redirect the parent of the iframe. check this out:

[Redirect parent window from an iframe action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action-using-javascript)

Comment: thanks a lot - it is written there that it is only possible if the iFrame is in the same domain - obviously this is not the case with a externally hosted fb canvas application.

Comment: sorry i only read the question, didn't mention in that what you where doing, didn't look at the tags