# Redirecting Parent URL from an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript that makes a iframe in a blogger and shows a html page that's in a different domain, and there is a button/image in the HTML page. and when someone clicks the button I need to redirect the parent page to another website.

is there a way I can do it?

```
top.location.href=
```

is not working.

Comment: You forgot window...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action-using-javascript

Comment: @Breezer — There is no need to mention the default object explicitly unless `top` is being masked in the local scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
top.location = ...
```

You can't access the properties of `location`, but you can overwrite the whole thing.

Alternatively, just use a link:

```
<a href="foo" target="_top">
```

Comment: I think the problem is in that the iframe and the blog are on the same domain, i can't use href because I do not want to show the link being redirected to

Comment: The user is going to know where they get redirected to eventually. It isn't something you can keep secret.