# Redirect to toplevel page with FullAjaxExceptionHandler

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

for exception handling of my JSF pages I'm using the FullAjaxExceptionHandler (thanks, BalusC ;-) ). The error handling works, but for some reasons I'm not able to redirect to a toplevel. I.e., the exception occurs in an iFrame (yes, I know that I shouldn't use it...) and the error page is displayed in this frame. How can I redirect to a toplevel page? With ?faces-redirect=true nothing happens.

TIA,

Ralf.

Answer (score 0):

The JSF Exception Handler does not actually send a redirect, but simply displays the error page instead of the requested page, so this cannot work.

Instead, you could place some JavaScript on the error page (see, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action-using-javascript)) that redirects the top window to some other URL which contains your real error page.

Comment: As far as I understood the question, OP actually wanted to "jump out of iframe" in case of an exception on the page inside the iframe. For that, JavaScript should be used on the exception page.