# How do I load a new page in the browser from within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a form inside of an iframe.
When I click a button on the form, I want the content of the outer containing page (NOT the content of the iframe) to be replace with the specified url.

If the form were not inside of an iframe this works ...

```
<input type='button' name='Next' value='Next Page'
onclick='window.location.replace("http://www.facebook.com");' />
```

The same code, inside of an iframe, replaces only the content of the iframe, not the content of the entire containing page.

How do I do it from inside of an iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.site.com";
```

As stated previously, will redirect the parent iframe. One thing to bear in mind is that both the website, and the site contained in the iframe need to be on the same domain for this to work, or you'll get an access denied exception.

So, if the site is 'www.site.com', and the iframe is 'iframe.site.com', in both pages you'll need to put:

```
document.domain = "site.com"
```

as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use top to access the parent:

```
top.location = "http://www.example.com"
```