# PHP redirection using header

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

My web structure is

---

```
         Header-of-page
```

---

Nav Link || iFrame

---

```
       Footer
```

---

I'm Trying to handle session timeout, when session has timeout I'm trying to redirect page to login page, this works fine(session timeout).

**Problem:**
When I'm redirecting the page,login page is displayed in iFrame, which is not expected.

How can I redirect to login page(whole window),rather than opeing it in iFrame.

**I Tried:**
1. using header
2. using javascript(Commented)

```
<?php session_start();

$timeout = 1; // Set timeout minutes
$timeout = $timeout * 60; // Converts minutes to seconds

if (isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) 
{
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if ($session_life > $timeout) 
    {
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: login.php?msg=timeout");
        // echo '<script language="javascript">'; 
                    // echo 'window.location.replace("login.php");';
                    // echo '</script>';
    }
}
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();

?>
```

Please guide me for this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Is your page within an iframe already?

Comment: @Grant : My login.php is not in iFrame,but my home.php(Structure mentioned above),which is page after login successed. Same structure is followed on all pages of web.

Comment: From what I understand you cannot redirect to a destination outside of an iframe (traverse the iframe).

Comment: @Grant : It seems like as you said,but stil hoping to get somthing,that will help to sort this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may use echo '<script language="javascript">window.location= "login.php?msg=timeout";</script>'; instead of  header("Location: login.php?msg=timeout");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: window.top.location.href = "http://www.site.com";

As long as this is on the same domain name.

More here: [Redirect parent window from an iframe action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action-using-javascript)

Comment: @Emma Was this helpful at all?

Comment: Now I have created,timeout page,and while loading it I have added your code. And I'm getting desired results and I'm sorted now. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 5):

use this one

in script `window.parent.location='http://localhost/users/login.php'`

or follow this link

https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/button-to-navigate-to-a-new-page-but-exit-the-iframe-too.1846291/

hope you will get solution.

Comment: This also get redirected in iFrame only.

Comment: <a href="http://localhost/users/login.php" target="_parent">Login</a> you can use this

Comment: @Biswajeet: your hyperlink options works well, but how can I click link onLoad or something. I tried $('#linkLogin').click() & $('#linkLogin').trigger.('click'). But its not redirecting automatically, Can you help me on this?

Comment: u can use window.location.replace("login.php");

Comment: @Biswajeet: I tried this already. Now just looking if my link is like this on page say timeout.html : <a href="localhost/users/login.php"; target="_parent">Login</a>. Link should get clicked automatically,cause this is the only way by which I can redirect to _parent(outside of iFrame), but it should be work direct rather than manually clicking. Thanks!

Comment: plz check your if block is properly conditioned because you wrote `$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();` after if then `if (isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) ` always return false so for this how will you go to if block you have to place `$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();` on else block

Comment: @Emma: This should work fine; I'm not sure why it wouldn't be working for you. Are you trying to do this in addition to the http redirect? It should be done instead of the http redirect; using both won't work right.

Comment: don't echo the scripts write it in this way it is warking `<?php session_start();

$timeout = 1; // Set timeout minutes
$timeout = $timeout * 60; // Converts minutes to seconds

if (isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) 
{
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if ($session_life > $timeout) 
    {
        session_destroy();
       // header("Location: login.php?msg=timeout");
  ?>
            <script language="javascript"> 
                     window.location.replace("login.php");
                     </script>
  <?php
    }
}
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();

?>`

Answer (score 3):

create form with `target="_parent"` and `action="login.php"`

and submit using `$(form).submit();`

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is than the iFrame is a another window in the partent window.

So when is begin redirected the iFrame only affect self (Not the parent or partents of the parent).

To don't use javascript we can put a link to login.php wich target the parent.

```
<a href="login.php" target="_top">Goto login.php</a>
```

`_top` will target the top window frame.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/a/target#target__li5 Read about target attribute set on _top.

The other method is using javascript:

```
window.top.location.assign("http://www.yoursite.com/login.php"); // Redirect
// window top frame to "http://yoursite.com/login.php"
```

Please read following links about javascript window documentation:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

In case yo want a "PHP" code, just use `echo`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

I hope this mightly helps.

Answer (score 2):

one of the probably mistakes,

if the encoding of this file is "UTF-8" it will create 2 hidden characters in the top of the file.

To fix this issue, try to change the encoding to "UTF-8 without BOM"

Answer (score 2):

you can put a exit; after the redirect

```
<?php session_start();

$timeout = 1; // Set timeout minutes
$timeout = $timeout * 60; // Converts minutes to seconds

if (isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) 
{
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if ($session_life > $timeout) 
    {
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: login.php?msg=timeout");
        exit(); // LOOK AT THIS LINE
        // echo '<script language="javascript">'; 
                    // echo 'window.location.replace("login.php");';
                    // echo '</script>';
    }
}
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
```

?>

Answer (score 2):

Try this way. Php redirection works before JS redirection so browser never runs JS. 
which that's the only way you can redirect whole window object.

```
<?php session_start();

$timeout = 1; // Set timeout minutes
$timeout = $timeout * 60; // Converts minutes to seconds

if (isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) 
{
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if ($session_life > $timeout) 
    {
        session_destroy();
        // header("Location: login.php?msg=timeout");
        echo '<script language="javascript">window.top.location.href = "login.php?msg=timeout";</script>'; 
    }
}
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to break the iframe. Try this..

```
if(this != top){
  top.location.href = this.location.href;
}
```

OR (with doc reference)

```
if(this != top){
  top.document.location.href = this.document.location.href;
}
```

Alternatively

```
this.top.location !== this.location && (this.top.location = this.location);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing this php being in the file running in the iframe in that case you have to instruct the parent window to redirect to login.

Echo the below code from php so when you page will render in browser, it will instruct the script to reload the page. But for the page not to load the rest of the page issue an `exit(0)`.  Your final script should look like below.

```
<?php session_start();

$timeout = 1; // Set timeout minutes
$timeout = $timeout * 60; // Converts minutes to seconds

if (isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) 
{
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if ($session_life > $timeout) 
    {
        session_destroy();        
        echo '<script language="javascript">';

        //Echo the exact full url to your login page
        echo 'window.parent.location="login.php?msg=timeout"'; 
        echo '</script>';
        exit(0); // So script won't go further displaying the page
    }
}
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();

?>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Check this solution out. I would put it before the header to prevent flickering. This way, your page will be prevented from swallowing itself.

http://usablelayout.com/articles/automatically-break-out-iframe

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    if (top.location!= self.location) {
        top.location = self.location.href
    }
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the login action on the same page, Header redirection will not work.

you can use simple the window.location.href='url';

---

For the login , you have to send the login query to new page, from there you can easily redirect easily...

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

php

```
echo "<script> window.location='forgot.php'</script>";
```

html

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="3;URL=http://google.com">
```