# to link a page within iframe and directed to a page without iframe

Tags: html, iframe

generally if we click on a link within a iframe window, the directed new page will be viewed within the iframe window. Can i have a way to have the new page displayed as such without being in the iframe window.

Thanks in Advance,
Samuel Mathews.

Comment: is it acceptable to use jQuery?

Comment: @melc.. i am open for using jquery..can you please share me the code.. (am not an expert in jquery)... thanks in advance!

Comment: `top.location.href = ...` should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You might know about the TARGET attribute for links. With it, you can load a linked page not in the current, but in a different named (I)FRAME / window.

There are also some special target names which might help you:

- **_parent:** Opens the page in the frame containing the current (I)FRAME
- **_top:** Opens a page in the current browser window as the top frame

There are also other special targets, but they are not important in this case. See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: thanks fnek!
 i am aware of _target.. but i need it in the current session.. any other suggestions please..

Comment: IMHO, this should internally work exactly like `window.location.href` and `top.location.href`. I didn´t try it, though, so you might be right.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can easily get any element from iframe, attach an event callback for example when clicked and act accordingly e.g. view a page anywher you require.

example,

http://jsfiddle.net/Lmx9X/show/

see the code here,

http://jsfiddle.net/Lmx9X/

**js**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
/*define a callback function to all anchors of iframe*/
        $('#subpage').contents().find('a').on('click',function(e){
/*prevent the default behaviour of navigating to the href of the anchors*/
            e.preventDefault();
/*do whatever you require, here for example a dialog is presented and navigates the parent page to the href url*/
            if (confirm('Prevented iframe from navigating to page. Do you want outer page to navigate instead??')) {
                var url = $(this).attr("href");
                window.location.href = (url.indexOf("#")==0?window.location.href:"")+$(this).attr("href");
            }else{
                alert("ok, will not navigate!");
            }
        });
    });
```

**html**

```
<iframe id="subpage" src="http://jsfiddle.net/s22Jm/1/show"></iframe>
```

Comment: thanks a lot... but i'm navigating to next page in javascript...using the below link..
document.location.href = 'abcd.com';

can you please help me modify the above code... such that the new page - abcd.com is seen as such without iframe window.. 
thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks to all those who helped..
     window.top.location.href

worked as expected... thanks again!
reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action-using-javascript