# Using PHP's header() to redirect to a different site, but the URL is still masked

Tags: php, url

And that's the problem.  This works:

```
header('Location: http://www.[whatever].com');
```

That statement works to get the user to the [whatever] site--it displays just fine within the client window of the browser.  The problem is that the URL is still being masked such that the user can't see the address string that she was just redirected to in the URL field, but rather she still sees the URL that she originally typed.

Is there a way to have the forward go through holistically, meaning not just the client area of the browser contains the final destination, but also the URL is the client destination's too?

Comment: Is the document with the header command not in the top frame of the browser?

Comment: Your answer probably lies here.. use PHP to output the JavaScript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action-using-javascript

Comment: "holistically" :) the document header is as much part of the "client area" of the browser. But if your document is embedded in a frame you need to forward to your top level frame.

Comment: I don't know.  I bought a domain and frame forwarded that to an individual page in my hosting acct. so that I could apply a counter to it.  I use header() to push the user from there to the site I really want it to redirect to.  It does that, displays that content, but the URL as originally typed is still persisted in the URL field.  (But I want it to be the final destination URL the user sees in the the URL field, to match the final everything else.)

Comment: Set Sail Media, I'll look at that JavaScript solution.  Thanks.

Comment: jtheman, I don't know if the document with the header command is in the top frame of the browser.  How do I find out?

Comment: Set Sail Media, it works great!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If PHP performs

```
header('Location: http://www.[whatever].com');
exit;
```

the browser redirects to the specified URL `http://www.[whatever].com`.

In case the redirect gets executed in an [iFrame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iframe#Frames) or an HTML frame, the URL isn't displayed in the the browser's URL field, since the original URL was not either.

**In any other case, the URL field will reflect the redirected URL.**