# Is it possible for an iframe to redirect the parent page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

It is possible for a iframe to redirect the page it is on?

Example:

You go to www.fuu.com

On fuu.com there is a iframe

In that iframe is a website the redirects to another website.

Is it possible for fuu.com to be redirected? instead on just the iframe going to another page?

Comment: What do you mean by redirected? But I'm pretty sure the answer is yes.

Comment: Something like `window.top.location.href = "http://example.com";` or `parent.document.location.href = "http://example.com";`

Comment: Oh, you mean you want the iframe to redirect the "parent" page? In that case no thats not possible. Edit: Actually I think I am wrong, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action-using-javascript

Answer (score 5):

<strike>No. An iframe is treated as a separate document with its own DOM. A redirect within the iframe is treated as a redirect only within that iframe.</strike>

In other words, The main page can not be redirected by an iframe.

EDIT: I was wrong. Consider the following situation

**Top Page**

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="redirect.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**redirect.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.top.location = "http://www.w3schools.com";
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

That does redirect the top page to w3schools.com

To prevent this type of thing, you can remove that by using the following

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="redirect.html" sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

In chrome, this would give you the following error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL 'http://127.0.0.1/scg/?search=&submit=Search' from frame with URL 'http://127.0.0.1/scg/iframeRedirect.html'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the 'allow-top-navigation' flag is not set.
```

The allow-scripts allows Javascript to still be executed in the iframe but removes window.top from allowing to execute. [Check this out](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp)

Comment: `window.top.location = "http://www.example.com";` ?

Comment: Google says different `"redirect from iframe"`

Comment: I was wrong. I did not consider `window.top`

Comment: If anyone is using Angular / TypeScript you'll need to use window.top.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com"