# How to redirect page inside iframe to another one but we must stay in iframe

Tags: javascript, redirect, iframe

Could anyone help me?
Is it possible to code this?
Redirect page inside iframe to another one but we must stay in iframe .
Without influence to parent site.
I tried many scripts but nothing worked.
Here is main code which i use. width and height is only for testing.
I use HTML5 sandbox to prevent iframe breaks to main site.
I need that to hide referer. Now parent site is showed as referer in iframed site, but i want to first site in iframe was used as referer to redirected one. Maybe it is crap, but i need that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<iframe  width="1025" height="350" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" src="URL"; </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to control from click in a link inside the iframe or from a link in the main page? Will your page be displayed in the iframe or is it  a external page?

Comment: see also [redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action)

Answer (score 15):

If you want the script to run from the frame:

```
document.location.href = "http://...";
```

If you want the parent page to redirect (change) the frame location:

HTML:

```
<iframe name="myFrame" ... />
```

JavaScript:

```
window.frames["myFrame"].location = "http://..."
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$(function() {
    if ('app' !== $('body').attr('id')){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            window.top.location.href = 'your redirect url'; 
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

in IFRAME use

```
sandbox="allow-top-navigation allow-scripts allow-forms"
```