# how to open a new tab when working with iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript

am working with Iframe and code below works fine by redirecting the parent iframe.

**Here is what am trying to achieve:**

I want when I click the button, the app will open a new tab/page on the browser that will take me **http://www.example.com**
instead of direct redirecting.  i guess it requires someything like
**_blank**  how can i achieve this

**here is the code**

```
function openNew_Tab() {
window.top.location.href = "http://www.example.com"; 
}

    <button onclick="openNew_Tab()">hello!</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect page inside iframe to another one but we must stay in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159920/how-to-redirect-page-inside-iframe-to-another-one-but-we-must-stay-in-iframe)

Comment: no Mr. Laode. between thanks for your response. Window.open() is the way

Answer (score 0):

**window.open()** function is what solve the problem as per below

```
function openNew_Tab() {
 window.open( 
              "https://example.com", "_blank"); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your intial assumption of blank_ was right to achieve this you can run the following code.

```
<button onclick="openNew_Tab()">hello!</button>

function openNew_Tab() {
window.open (
 "http://www.example.com", "_blank");
}
```

Comment: The answer loaded in just after I posted sorry