# Redirect parent iFrame from nested iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, iframe

I saw this question on redirection iFrames [Redirect parent window from an iframe action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action) but the answer addressed redirecting the entire page.

The redirect was using:

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
```

Is there a way to redirect nested iFrames?

ie.

```
<browser>
    <iframe src="someSrc">
        <!--iFrame page-->
        <iframe src="nestedSrc"></iframe>
    </iframe>
</browser>
```

So from the `nestedSrc` redirect `someSrc` to another page instead of redirecting the browser page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the parent iframe's domain, you can simply redirect it using:

```
window.parent.location = 'http://new.location.com';
```

Small `parent`/`top` example

```
<Browser>
    <iframe1>
        <iframe2>
        </iframe2>
    </iframe1>
</Browser>
```

Inside iframe2 the following are true:

```
window.parent.parent == window.top // true
window.parent == window.top.frames[0] // true
```

Note: the following example presumes `browser` and `iframe` `1` & `2` all are from the same domain

Comment: I know about the domain issues, but I do know that for redirecting the browser from an `iFrame` is allowed to be cross domain, is the same true for redirecting a parent iFrame?

Comment: Yes, the cross domain communication is blocked also between two `iframe`s not only an `iframe` and `browser` (`window.top`)