# iframe: Redirect to externel url

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, iframe, yii

I am working on a website in `Yii`. The situation is like this. In the website, the `users` are provided a piece of code that is like this:

```
<iframe height="700" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:100%;border:none" src="http://djoneclick.com/index.php?r=webservice/form&id=6b720ff1c3cdce6c278e784a3228fd9fadc6d864" title="" >
<a href="/index.php?r=webservice/form&id=6b720ff1c3cdce6c278e784a3228fd9fadc6d864" title="">

</a>
</iframe>
```

`User` can embed this anywhere they want and take inquiries from the desired audience. This `iframe` includes the `src` which is a `form` that submits to a `controller` in `Yii`. In the `controller`, upon having a specif `if` condition `true`, it `redirects` to the externel `url`. It redirects but the contents of the `url` (to which it is redirected) are displayed in the `iframe`. What I want is to actually `redirect` to that `url`.
 I have spent hours upon `R&D` for this but could not find any solution. any help?

Comment: Maybe this helps you out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action

Comment: This states to use this, `window.top.location.href = "http://www.example.com";` But i dont know, where to use this in my code?

Comment: Are you making ajax call while submit a form?

Comment: No, form is submitting as does the normal form.

Comment: Do you have access to the code of the iframe content? Would it be possible for you to move the condition check to the client side? If so, you could overwrite the onsubmit-event of the form, you are sending, with javascript-code that checks the given condition and then, if it is true, executes the code line stated above...

Comment: Submit a form using Ajax and once you get response from ajax execute   `window.top.location.href = "http://www.yoursite.com";`

Comment: sandeepsure's suggestion is even better since it allows you to keep the condition check in the controller

Comment: @sandeepsure this seems logical, But can u kindly put some code as an example?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#idForm").submit(function() {

var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           window.top.location.href = "http://www.yoursite.com";
       }
     });

      return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this after the condition is true in your `controller`:

```
echo "<script>";
echo "this.parent.location.href = '$externel_url'";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: Oh great, Works like a charm! (y)