# Hard Refresh (F5) on the parent page when in the iframe through PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I am trying to instigate a hard refresh (F5) on the parent page but since I am working within an iframe, I am unable to do so.

I tried all of these following but either the refresh happens within the frame or complete page refresh isn't achieved.

### JS within PHP

```
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                parent.window.location.href='".$my_url."';
</SCRIPT>");

echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                parent.window.top.location.href ='".$my_url."';
                </SCRIPT>");
exit();
```

### PHP Refresh

```
  Header('Location: '.$my_url);
```

Nothing is working.

The reason I am hoping to achieve this because some of the elements in the page will only be re-activated when the page refreshes completely.

Hopefully, there is some way through which we can have a complete refresh through PHP.

Comment: have you tried just a simple `window.location`?

Comment: Yes, it just redirects iframe not complete page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect parent window from an iframe action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action)

Comment: I already went through all of those. Sorry