# Youtube embed live chat login can not redirect back to my site

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Youtube recently release embed live chat

ref:https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549?hl=en

but when a user use this embed iframe to login youtube

it will not redirect back to my site

is there a parameter that can set it redirect back to my site?

something like:

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=(videoId)&is_popout=1&embed_domain=(domain)&redirect=(siteUrl)" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

does anyone kown?

Comment: Check this[SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action) and this [page](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/698339/How-to-redirect-page-in-Iframe) if it can help you.

Comment: thanks for your replay, but it seems not my solution, I think this problem only youtube engineer can solve it, because of youtube api need to add some params to make redirect correct. thank you~