# asp.net IFrame redirection to another website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I am developing a functionality where I have a IFrame inside aspx page.

Inside IFrame I am loading another website(i.e. Third party website). Inside that website when user click on a button on that third party website , that website redirect to another page on my website.

This new page (after redirection) is loaded in to IFrame, instead I want to load it to parent page.

How can I implement it.

So Basically scnario is like given below

I have a website (say abc.com\page1.aspx)

inside page1.aspx I am loading URL : xyz.com inside  an Iframe. in Page_load event.

Please note I am loading a totally different website (i.e xyz.com) inside Iframe.

---

Now
Inside xyz.com\xyzpage2.aspx - there is a button, on click on that button another page opens (say xyzpage3.aspx).

I want to open xyzpage3.aspx in parent window and not in IFrame.

would it be possible to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Show the code you made, and where is the problem or what should be changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect parent window from an iframe action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action)

Comment: @mjwills I think OP has no control over the website inside the iframe. So i doubt this will be possible what OP wants.